# :nth-child recipe for alternating colors

Tags: css

I have a bunch of div tags that are 50% in width, which allows them to sit in a grid 2 tags wide. I am really struggling to define alternating background colours to give an effect similar to a chequerboard. As you can see in the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fobc6fs5/), all colours sit on the same side regardless of the recipes I have tried, so for the purposes of this question I've reverted to (odd) and (even).

I'm not able to specify particular classes on alternate div's as the content of each block is generated via a Wordpress query.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  height 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
div:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
div:nth-child(even) { background: blue; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
div:nth-child(4n+1), div:nth-child(4n+4) { background: red; }
div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3) { background: blue; }
```

```html
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
<div>Block</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. Not sure why I couldn't crack that!

Answer (score 2):

Make all of those divs have blue background to begin with, and then use

```
div:nth-child(4n+1), div:nth-child(4n+4) { background: red; }
```

to select every 1st and 4th one out of every four.

https://jsfiddle.net/fobc6fs5/3/